# Show that if $X_{n}$ is Hausdorff for every $n,$ then the product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} X_{n}$ is also Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $X_{n}$ is  Hausdorff for every $n,$ then the product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} X_{n}$ is also Hausdorff.

Could anyone help me in proving this please?

**Definition:**

A space $X$ is Hausdorff if for every distinct pair of points $a,b \in X,$ there are open sets $U, V \subseteq X$ s.t. $a \in U, b \in V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset.$

Answer (score 4):

Take two unequal points $(p_1,p_2, \cdots), (q_1, q_2, \cdots)$ in $\prod_{n=1}^\infty X_n$. There must be some index $i$ such that $p_i \neq q_i$. Then, use the fact that $X_i$ is Hausdorff to find disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X_i$, containing $p_i$ and $q_i$, respectively. What can you say about the sets $$X_1 \times X_2 \times \cdots \times X_{i-1}\times U \times X_{i+1} \times \cdots$$ and $$X_1 \times X_2 \times \cdots \times X_{i-1} \times V \times X_{i+1} \times \cdots$$?

Comment: I think it's nicer to write those sets as $\pi_i^{-1}[U]$, and $\pi_i^{-1}[V]$ respectively. No dots notations, and openness and disjointness are immediate.

Comment: The size of the index set can be anything really, we're not limited to countable sets.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma could you please show me the details of your thoughts by posting an answer to the question please?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_i, i \in I$ be *any* non-empty collection of Hausdorff spaces, and $X=\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ gets the product topology, of which we only have to know that all projections $\pi_i: X \to X_i$ are continuous.

If $x \neq y$ are two distinct points in $X$, then there is some index $i_0 \in I$ such that $x_{i_0} \neq y_{i_0}$ (by definition of the Cartesian product $x=y$ iff $\forall i: x_i = y_i$, and negation of the latter is $\exists i: x_i \neq y_i$.)

As $X_{i_0}$ is Hausdorff there are open sets $U,V \subseteq X_{i_0}$ such that

$$x_{i_0} \in U, y_{i_0} \in V, U \cap V = \emptyset$$

Then by continuity of $\pi_{i_0}$, $U':= \pi_{i_0}^{-1}[U]$ and $V':= \pi_{i_0}^{-1}[V]$ are open in $X$ and $$U' \cap V'= \pi_{i_0}^{-1}[U] \cap  \pi_{i_0}^{-1}[V] = \pi_{i_0}^{-1}[U \cap V] = \pi_{i_0}^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset$$ and by definition $x \in U'$ and $y \in V'$.

So $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Is this proof for countable products only?

Comment: @Mathstupid no, this works for all non-empty  index sets.